# Issue with Sorting in Power BI Desktop Table Visual

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm displaying my data in Power BI Desktop table visual using SQL Server Stored Procedure data source. I need data to be sorted in particular user-requested order (there are only 5 rows in the data output). For this purpose I did the following:

1. Created "dummy" column in SQL Server SP to reflect the ordering requirements (values 1-5)
2. Specified dummy column in Order By clause for SP output.
3. In Power BI Desktop I navigated to Power Query Editor and sorted data table by the dummy column explicitly.

Still, after all these steps, data in table visual is sorted differently. Please note dummy column is NOT displayed on table visual (and is not supposed to be). Also, NO manual sorting has been applied to the table visual (both Sort Ascending and Sort Descending options are blurred for the Table Visual).

How can I fix this issue?

Appreciate your help.

P.S. Here is the picture of not displaying Column Tools when clicking on a column:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTXFR.jpg

Answer (score 1):

What you may want to try to do is select the column you want to have sorted and set it to sort by the dummy column you have created. This uses your chosen field as the display field but will sort it by your dummy field.

This is very commonly used when sorting months or days of the week where you want to see, say, a day name on an axis but don't want it sorted alphabetically but rather by the order of the day in the week.

Sample screen shot below taken from these [PowerBI Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column?tabs=powerbi-desktop).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for some reason I can't get to Column Details tab even when I highlight one of the fields/calculated columns in Fields pane. But interesting thing is that when I sort the data in Data view, it does not carry over the sorting to Report View. Also, the strange thing is that Power BI doesn't pick up correct sorting from the backend query with specified Order By clause.

Comment: Backend order by is irrelevant, PowerBI controls all the sorting. Always explicitly set the ordering on a visual if you want predictable behaviour. Column details tab should be available for columns (not measures).

Comment: I added the image link showing my Power Bi environment not displaying Column Tools when highlighting column: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTXFR.jpg

Comment: It looks like you have the May 2020 version of PowerBI desktop. Can you try upgrading to current?

Comment: Hi Murray, sorry for late response. No, I can't, unfortunately our Power BI Server supports only May 2020 edition, and our admins do not have plans to upgrade it

Comment: That is sad to hear @DanS. - PowerBI is evolving so rapidly, 2020 is two years ago but it feels like a decade.